# google bigquery Querying sets of tables using wildcard tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 100s of tables with the below naming conventions.

```
click001
click001_meta
click002
click002_meta
click003
click003_meta
click004
click004_meta
.........
.........
click00n
click00n_meta
```

I would like to query these tables using wildcard tables in bigquery (standard) excluding *_meta tables. Resultset should only be from (click001,click002,click003..click00n)

I have tried something like this, but results still has the data from *meta tables.

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as tp, *
FROM `abc.clicks*`
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, "_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]")
```

Do we have any solutions in Standard Dialect?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no problem has been found. See more at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111659626

Comment: Thanks for your help.   Do you have suggestions/solutions to get results only from click00n but not from click00n_meta using wildcard search?

Comment: You are not getting any results from the "meta" tables. Schema is, but no rows from those tables are getting in.

Comment: Two choices going forward: You can either not use the "*" expansion, or enter a feature request on the BQ issue tracker "Please don't determine schema until filtering tables after an * expansion"

Comment: Sorry. Actual results show data from meta table which has different schema than the click00n table.   At this moment I assume wild card table search feature is at faulty or incomplete state to serve in production and I go with your first choice.   On that issues tracker, I have requested them for the feature you suggested.  Thanks for trying to help, appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, `_` means "any character", not underscore, so you may need to escape the underscore with a backslash instead. Alternatively, you can probably just use a filter with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as tp, *
FROM `abc.clicks*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX NOT LIKE '%meta'
```

Comment: Didn't work as expected. Query output still shows data from click00x_meta.
Thanks!

Comment: So...what is the value of `tp` in the query results, then?

Comment: For example, I could see tp as 002.  The output came from click002_meta.

Comment: same as in comment for my answer - for click002_meta it would be 002_meta. so if you see just 002 - it means that respective table was click002

Comment: SELECT  _TABLE_SUFFIX tp, count(1) cnt FROM `abc.clicks*` WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'\d$') group by _TABLE_SUFFIX 

As per assumption, this query return count only for clicksnnn tables, but the output count is from both clicksnnn +clicksnnn_meta.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make any sense to me. If `tp` doesn't have `meta` in it, then it wasn't one of the meta tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as tp, *
FROM `abc.click*`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'\d$')
```

Comment: Thanks, still I have the same results. what does '\d$' stands for ?

Comment: 1) there is no way to have same result - you doing something else that is outside your question - please verify!!! 2) '\d$' means 'digit at the end of string'

Comment: Thanks Mikhail.  The problem is _TABLE_SUFFIX.  for example, _TABLE_SUFFIX  return 003 for both clicks003 and clicks0003_meta

Comment: Thanks. Logically it is correct.  But if I specify  * after tp, it returns data from _meta table.   Maybe it is a big query bug.

Comment: are you saying that you still have a problem with all this (even though logically it is correct)? let us know  - if so we need t figure out how troubleshoot your case

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111659626)

Question complains "I see data from excluded tables", but what's really happening is "I see columns from the excluded tables". This happens because the schema is determined first - but no data passed the filters.

---

Can you run this test:

```
SELECT _table_suffix ts 
FROM `abc.clicks*` 
WHERE _table_suffix NOT LIKE '%meta' 
GROUP BY 1
```

That's all you need to exclude "meta" tables. If the result of the query brings any table with the "meta" suffix, please reply with a job id to file a bug.

Comment: No it didn't work.  Mikhail Berlyant/Elliott shared the similar inputs.

Job ID    blink-194619:US.bquijob_6f8c6005_164b45eb5ca
SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as tp, * FROM `aetna.click*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX NOT LIKE '%meta'

Comment: wait... you are telling us that query returned some rows, with strings ending in 'meta'???  (I can not personally look at the job id, but a job id will help people that can)

Comment: (for someone to check the job id, please add an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)

Comment: Here are we are talking about the wildcard tables but not the actual rows.  As per your logic, we should not see records from _meta* tables.  But it in reality, it does data from _meta* tables.

Comment: Time for a bug report with that bug id then! Best way to get this checked

Comment: I did.  Thanks, Experts!